FLAML automl prediction probabilities do not match the prediction
i am using flaml automl on fabric for a classification exercise.
In order to leverage spark, i must use to_pandas_on_spark.
the features are already assembled in a vector.
from flaml.automl.spark.utils import to_pandas_on_spark
psdf = to_pandas_on_spark(train_df)

Fitting is successful, so i want to predict my test data. best estimator is lgbm_spark.
Next to evaluate I will need a final dataframe that includes the target alpha column, the prediction, and the probability, as well as id columns that exist in test_df (pdate & zm).
psdf_test = to_pandas_on_spark(test_df.select("features"))
y_pred = automl.predict(psdf_test) 

The above will return a pyspark.pandas.series.Series with a single column of predicitions
y_pred_prob = automl.predict_proba(psdf_test)

The above will return a pyspark.pandas.series.Series where each row is a list of three probabilities.
Usually the first is the probability for class 0, the second for class 1, and the third for class 2.
To bring everything together, i plan to convert everything to a pandas dataframe, and then concatenate.
#predictions
y_pred_pd = y_pred.to_pandas()  # Convert to pandas Series
y_pred_pd = y_pred_pd.to_frame(name="prediction")  # Convert to pandas DataFrame with column name 'prediction'

# probabilities
y_pred_prob_pd = y_pred_prob.to_pandas()  # Convert to pandas Series
#y_pred_prob_pd = y_pred_prob_pd.to_frame(name="probability")  # Convert to DataFrame with column name 'probability'

# Convert test_df to a pandas DataFrame to join back with identifiers
test_df_pd = test_df.toPandas()

#concatenate the three dataframes
result_df = pd.concat([test_df_pd, y_pred_pd, y_pred_prob_pd], axis=1)

It works, but here is the problem: The highest probability does not match the prediction.

Note that even if the assumed class order is incorrect, the prediction is still inconsistent with the highest probability.

why the discrepancy?
is there a cleaner way of achieving my desired result?


Is your issue still not resolved?

add your sample data.

Also what is the class order? you check properly that.

@RakeshGovindula yes still not resolved

@JayashankarGS I did it’s in the snapshot. How do I check properly please?

Need data to reproduce error. The features column is not full. Please add it in text.

check the class order once, if it is matching to your y_pred_prob

@Kelaref did you get the index column while assembling the features?
